# Converting to SQL Server Geography from Pandas

Tags: sql-server, pandas, sqlalchemy, geospatial

From a CSV, I need to upload latitude and longitude coordinates (float) as geometry to SQL Server. How do I do this through the to_sql() method from Pandas (going through sqlalchemy)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SQL Server supports implicit conversion from strings in the Well-Known Text (WKT) format to geography.  So you should be able so simply add a column in your Data Frame with data in the form `POINT(LON LAT)`, eg

```
'POINT(-122.34900 47.65100)'
```

eg

```
drop table if exists #foo
go
create table #foo(id int, g geography)

insert into #foo(id, g) values (1,'POINT(-122.34900 47.65100)')

select *, g.STSrid
from #foo
```

Comment: When I did this, it came in came into SQL as a varchar(max)?

Comment: This is the the content of the varchar: POINT( -73.8922 40.8242 )

Comment: Did you create a new table or load an existing one?

Comment: I am overwriting a table using the to_sql() method in pandas.

Comment: I think you'll need to create the table ahead of writing to it if you want it to have a geography column.

Comment: how do I cast the varchar column as a geography column using SQL?

Comment: I got it to work with an "ALTER TABLE <tablename> ALTER COLUMN geom geography. I uploaded as a varchar with to_sql and then ran alter table to cast the varchar as a geography.